# How did people from the Stone Age know the moon was another round object like Earth?

Tags: dr.stone

In the Stone Age, people believed the moon and stars were light sources made for us to look at. That changed in the 1600's with the invention of the telescope. But in Dr Stone: New World part 2 episode 10, the inhabitants of Ishigami Village who lived in the Stone Age, knew the moon was another round object like Earth, and they understand when Senku wants to go to the moon.

Was this reality explained to them at any moment during the story?
How did people from the Stone Age know the moon was another round object like Earth?

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple reasons that they would know the moon is round.

### The moon, as seen by the naked eye, is obviously round

Even the [ancient Greeks knew that the moon was round](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/2268), well before there were telescopes. Unlike other planetary bodies, which are further away and look like blobs in the sky (if visible at all), we can see the phases of the moon, which look exactly like a round object being lit from different angles:

> [image: phases of a tennis ball]

This is not the only reason to think the moon is round, but it is the most obvious. The invention of better telescopes in the 1600s allowed scientists to [see the phases of Venus](https://www.cabinet.ox.ac.uk/phases-venus-1610-23) too and better map out the orbits of the planets, finally disproving (eventually) the geocentric model of the solar system—there was never a question of whether the planets were round or not at this point in history.

### The origin of Ishigami Village

[A Hundred Nights and a Thousand Skies](https://dr-stone.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_17) (e17) explains that:

> The astronauts in the ISS, including Senku's father Byakuya Ishigami, who did not get petrified, founded Ishigami Village (thus its name). Byakuya created 100 tales which were to be passed down generation to generation containing information essential to humanity's survival, with Ruri being the one in the current generation who knows them as priestess.
>
>  Therefore it's possible—likely even—that the information was never forgotten in the first place, being either passed down informally via word of mouth or formally via the tales.